# latexmk to show error in quickfix

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Please consider this small and **wrong** latex. I am using `vim` as editor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\hello
\end{document}
```

I am trying to compile it using (I use vim-latex, but for compile, I use my own ):

```
!latexmk -pdflua -pvc -quiet -synctex=1 -shell-escape  --halt-on-error %
```

But, the problem is it doesn't show error in quickfix window.

Any help please?

Comment: oops....no! I meant `\hello` so that it yeilds error. I want to catch error in `vim` `quickfix`

Comment: probably you havn't read the text, check the code only. It was clearly written its wrong, and a seasonal latex user should understand that, imho. BTW, `vim` is tagged, and in main text.

Comment: Again a non vim user does not know what quickfix is. There is no need to be rude

Comment: Thats why its clearly tagged for vim, and in main text as well.

Comment: I'm still saying the question is very poorly worded.

Comment: the quickfix panel is not meant for the output of arbitrary shell output, it requires filtering the errors, but anyway you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115534/vim-redirect-output-to-quickfix